# Undeclared identifier 'x';

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to convert a script made on pine-script version 2 to version 4, I fixed most of the errors, but I'm unable to fix the "Undeclared identifier" ones.

```
line 30: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 31: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 35: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 38: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 44: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 45: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 49: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 52: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 58: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 59: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 63: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 64: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 65: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 66: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 67: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 68: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 69: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 70: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 71: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 71: Undeclared identifier 'sellPerfection';
line 72: Undeclared identifier 'sellPerfection';
line 74: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 75: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 76: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 77: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 78: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 79: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 80: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 81: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 82: Undeclared identifier 'buyPerfection';
line 83: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 83: Undeclared identifier 'buyPerfection';
line 87: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 88: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 92: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 92: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTSupport';
line 93: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTSupport';
line 93: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 94: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTSupportIntact';
line 94: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTSupport';
line 96: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 96: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTResistance';
line 97: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTResistance';
line 97: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 98: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTResistanceIntact';
line 98: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTResistance';
line 103: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 104: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 105: Undeclared identifier 'sinceBuyNine';
line 105: Undeclared identifier 'sinceSellNine';
line 106: Undeclared identifier 'lastSetupIsBuy';
line 107: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTResistance';
line 107: Undeclared identifier 'sinceBuyNine';
line 108: Undeclared identifier 'lastSetupIsSell';
line 108: Undeclared identifier 'brokeResistance';
line 111: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 111: Undeclared identifier 'lastBuyLowestVal';
line 112: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTResistance';
line 112: Undeclared identifier 'lastBuyLowestVal';
line 113: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 113: Undeclared identifier 'lastBuySetupRange';
line 113: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastBuyRange';
line 114: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastBuyRange';
line 114: Undeclared identifier 'lastBuySetupRange';
line 117: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 117: Undeclared identifier 'lastBuyHighestClose';
line 118: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 118: Undeclared identifier 'lastBuyLowestClose';
line 119: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 119: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTResistance';
line 119: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastBuyHighestVal';
line 120: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 120: Undeclared identifier 'lastBuyLowestVal';
line 120: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastBuyLowestVal';
line 122: Undeclared identifier 'lastBuyHighestClose';
line 122: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastBuyHighestVal';
line 123: Undeclared identifier 'lastBuyLowestClose';
line 123: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastBuyLowestVal';
line 125: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 125: Undeclared identifier 'sinceBuyNine';
line 125: Undeclared identifier 'sinceSecondLastBuy';
line 126: Undeclared identifier 'sinceSecondLastBuy';
line 126: Undeclared identifier 'sinceSellNine';
line 126: Undeclared identifier 'sinceBuyNine';
line 127: Undeclared identifier 'aboveSecondLastBuyRange';
line 127: Undeclared identifier 'belowSecondLastBuyRange';
line 127: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetupBetweenTwoBuys';
line 130: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 133: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 133: Undeclared identifier 'sinceBuyNine';
line 134: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 135: Undeclared identifier 'buySetup';
line 135: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 138: Undeclared identifier 'buyCancelationFilter';
line 141: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 142: Undeclared identifier 'initiateBuyCountdown';
line 147: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 148: Undeclared identifier 'newBuySetupDuringCountdown';
line 148: Undeclared identifier 'buyCancelationQualifier1';
line 148: Undeclared identifier 'buyCancelationQualifier2';
line 152: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 154: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 156: Undeclared identifier 'newBuySetupDuringCountdown';
line 156: Undeclared identifier 'buyCancelationQualifier1';
line 156: Undeclared identifier 'buyCancelationQualifier2';
line 159: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdownCompleted';
line 162: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 165: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 166: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 167: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 168: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 169: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 170: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 171: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 172: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 173: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 174: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 175: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 176: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 177: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 178: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 183: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTSupport';
line 183: Undeclared identifier 'sinceSellNine';
line 184: Undeclared identifier 'lastSetupIsBuy';
line 184: Undeclared identifier 'brokeSupport';
line 187: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 187: Undeclared identifier 'lastSellHighestVal';
line 188: Undeclared identifier 'lastSellHighestVal';
line 188: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTSupport';
line 189: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 189: Undeclared identifier 'lastSellSetupRange';
line 189: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastSellRange';
line 190: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastSellRange';
line 190: Undeclared identifier 'lastSellSetupRange';
line 193: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 193: Undeclared identifier 'lastSellHighestClose';
line 194: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 194: Undeclared identifier 'lastSellLowestClose';
line 195: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 195: Undeclared identifier 'lastSellHighestVal';
line 195: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastSellHighestVal';
line 196: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 196: Undeclared identifier 'TDSTSupport';
line 196: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastSellLowestVal';
line 198: Undeclared identifier 'lastSellHighestClose';
line 198: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastSellHighestVal';
line 199: Undeclared identifier 'lastSellLowestClose';
line 199: Undeclared identifier 'secondLastSellLowestVal';
line 200: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 200: Undeclared identifier 'sinceSellNine';
line 200: Undeclared identifier 'sinceSecondLastSell';
line 201: Undeclared identifier 'sinceSecondLastSell';
line 201: Undeclared identifier 'sinceBuyNine';
line 201: Undeclared identifier 'sinceSellNine';
line 202: Undeclared identifier 'aboveSecondLastSellRange';
line 202: Undeclared identifier 'belowSecondLastSellRange';
line 202: Undeclared identifier 'buySetupBetweenTwoSells';
line 205: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 205: Undeclared identifier 'sinceSellNine';
line 206: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 207: Undeclared identifier 'sellSetup';
line 207: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 210: Undeclared identifier 'sellCancelationFilter';
line 213: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 214: Undeclared identifier 'initiateSellCountdown';
line 219: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 220: Undeclared identifier 'newSellSetupDuringCountdown';
line 220: Undeclared identifier 'sellCancelationQualifier1';
line 220: Undeclared identifier 'sellCancelationQualifier2';
line 224: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 226: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 228: Undeclared identifier 'newSellSetupDuringCountdown';
line 228: Undeclared identifier 'sellCancelationQualifier1';
line 231: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdownCompleted';
line 234: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 237: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 238: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 239: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 240: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 241: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 242: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 243: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 244: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 245: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 246: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 247: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 248: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 249: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 250: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 254: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 254: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdownLow';
line 255: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 255: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdownLow';
line 255: Undeclared identifier 'buyRiskLine';
line 256: Undeclared identifier 'buyRiskLine';
line 256: Undeclared identifier 'buyCountdown';
line 257: Undeclared identifier 'buyRiskLineIntact';
line 257: Undeclared identifier 'buyRiskLine';
line 259: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 259: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdownHigh';
line 260: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 260: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdownHigh';
line 260: Undeclared identifier 'sellRiskLine';
line 261: Undeclared identifier 'sellRiskLine';
line 261: Undeclared identifier 'sellCountdown';
line 262: Undeclared identifier 'sellRiskLineIntact';
line 262: Undeclared identifier 'sellRiskLine'
```

```
// ==============================================
// TD Sequential - Setup and Countdown
// Igor Molnar, 2018.
// ==============================================
// Tom DeMark's Sequential indicator with both Setup and Countdown components implemented 
// according to the rules outlined in: DeMark Indicators by Jason Perl (Bloomberg Market Essentials)
// 
// Feel free to PM me your comments, suggestions and bug reports at https://www.tradingview.com/u/Yngvar/

//@version=4
study("TD Sequential (Setup and Countdown)", overlay = true)

// OPTIONAL PARAMETERS //

transp            = input(0, title="Number Transparency")
priceFlipRequired = input(true, title="Setup - Require price flip for initiation")
showBuySetup      = input(true, title="Setup - Show Buy Setup")
showSellSetup     = input(true, title="Setup - Show Sell Setup")
showOnlySetupNine = input(false,title="Setup - Show Only Completed Nines")
showResistance    = input(true, title="Setup Trend - Show Resistance Lines")
showSupport       = input(true, title="Setup Trend - Show Support Lines")
showBuyCountdown  = input(true, title="Countdown - Show Buy Countdown")
showSellCountdown = input(true, title="Countdown - Show Sell Countdown")
showRiskLines     = input(false, title="Risk Lines - Show (Beta)")

// PRICE FLIP AND SETUP //

buySetup = if close < close[4]
    if priceFlipRequired
        if close[1] > close[5] or 0 < nz(buySetup[1])
            nz(buySetup[1]) + 1
        else
            0
    else
        if nz(buySetup[1]) == 9
            1
        else
            nz(buySetup[1]) + 1
else
    0

sellSetup = if close > close[4]
    if priceFlipRequired
        if close[1] < close[5] or 0 < nz(sellSetup[1])
            nz(sellSetup[1]) + 1
        else
            0
    else
        if nz(sellSetup[1]) == 9
            1
        else
            nz(sellSetup[1]) + 1
else
    0

// PERFECTED SETUP CONDITIONS //

sellPerfection = sellSetup==9 and ((high > high[2] and high > high[3]) or (high[1] > high[2] and high[1] > high[3]))
buyPerfection  = buySetup==9 and ((low < low[2] and low < low[3]) or (low[1] < low[2] and low[1] < low[3]))

// NUMBER PLOTS //

plotchar(sellSetup==1 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='1',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==2 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='2',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==3 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='3',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==4 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='4',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==5 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='5',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==6 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='6',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==7 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='7',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==8 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='8',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotshape(sellSetup==9 and showSellSetup and not sellPerfection,style=shape.arrowdown,size=size.small,color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,text="9",textcolor=color.green,transp=transp)
plotshape(sellPerfection and showSellSetup,style=shape.arrowdown,size=size.small,color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,text="9P",textcolor=color.green,transp=transp)
 
plotchar(buySetup==1 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='1',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==2 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='2',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==3 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='3',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==4 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='4',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==5 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='5',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==6 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='6',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==7 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='7',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp) 
plotchar(buySetup==8 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='8',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotshape(buyPerfection and showBuySetup,style=shape.arrowup,size=size.small,color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,text="9P",textcolor=color.red,transp=transp)
plotshape(buySetup==9 and not buyPerfection and showBuySetup,style=shape.arrowup,size=size.small,color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,text="9",textcolor=color.red,transp=transp)

// ALERTS // 

alertcondition(barssince(sellSetup == 9) == 1, title='Sell Setup Completed', message='TD Sell Setup Completed')
alertcondition(barssince(buySetup == 9) == 1, title='Buy Setup Completed', message='TD Buy Setup Completed')

// SETUP TREND LINES //

TDSTSupport = sellSetup == 9 ? lowest(low, 9) : nz(TDSTSupport[1])
TDSTSupportIntact = close >= TDSTSupport and (barssince(close < TDSTSupport) > barssince(sellSetup == 9))
plot(TDSTSupportIntact and showSupport ? TDSTSupport : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.green)

TDSTResistance = buySetup == 9 ? highest(high, 9) : nz(TDSTResistance[1])
TDSTResistanceIntact = close <= TDSTResistance and (barssince(close > TDSTResistance) > barssince(buySetup == 9))
plot(TDSTResistanceIntact and showResistance ? TDSTResistance : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.red)
 
// COUNTDOWN - BUY //

// Cancelation Filter 
sinceBuyNine      = barssince(buySetup == 9)
sinceSellNine     = barssince(sellSetup == 9)
lastSetupIsBuy    = sinceBuyNine < sinceSellNine // last completed setup is a buy setup
lastSetupIsSell   = not lastSetupIsBuy
brokeResistance   = barssince(low > TDSTResistance) < sinceBuyNine // did full candle trade above tdst resistance generated by last buy setup
buyCancelationFilter = lastSetupIsSell or brokeResistance

// Cancelation Qualifier 1 - Last buy setup larger than the one before but less then 1.618 times it's size
lastBuyLowestVal         = buySetup == 9 ? lowest(low, 9) : (buySetup > 9 ? min(nz(lastBuyLowestVal[1]), low) : nz(lastBuyLowestVal[1]))
lastBuySetupRange        = TDSTResistance - lastBuyLowestVal
secondLastBuyRange       = buySetup == 9 ? nz(lastBuySetupRange[1]) : nz(secondLastBuyRange[1])
buyCancelationQualifier1 = (secondLastBuyRange <= lastBuySetupRange) and (lastBuySetupRange < 1.618 * secondLastBuyRange)

// Cancelation Qualifier 2 - Last buy setup not within the last one
lastBuyHighestClose      = buySetup == 9 ? highest(close, 9) : (buySetup > 9 ? max(nz(lastBuyHighestClose[1]), close) : nz(lastBuyHighestClose[1]))
lastBuyLowestClose       = buySetup == 9 ? lowest(close, 9) : (buySetup > 9 ? min(nz(lastBuyLowestClose[1]), close) : nz(lastBuyLowestClose[1]))
secondLastBuyHighestVal  = buySetup == 9 ? TDSTResistance[1] : nz(secondLastBuyHighestVal[1])
secondLastBuyLowestVal   = buySetup == 9 ? nz(lastBuyLowestVal[1]) : nz(secondLastBuyLowestVal[1])

aboveSecondLastBuyRange  = lastBuyHighestClose > secondLastBuyHighestVal
belowSecondLastBuyRange  = lastBuyLowestClose < secondLastBuyLowestVal

sinceSecondLastBuy       = buySetup == 9 ? nz(sinceBuyNine[1])+1 : nz(sinceSecondLastBuy[1])+1
sellSetupBetweenTwoBuys  = sinceSecondLastBuy > sinceSellNine and sinceSellNine > sinceBuyNine
buyCancelationQualifier2 = aboveSecondLastBuyRange or belowSecondLastBuyRange or sellSetupBetweenTwoBuys

// Recycle Qualifier
recycleQualifier = buySetup == 18 // To do, a bit unclear

// Miscellaneous
initiateBuyCountdown  = (close <= low[2]) and (buySetup == 9 or barssince(close[1] <= low[3])+1 > sinceBuyNine)
buyCountdownCompleted = low[1] <= valuewhen(nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0)
newBuySetupDuringCountdown = barssince(buySetup == 9) < barssince(buyCountdown[1] == 1)
        
// Countdown Logic
buyCountdown = if buyCancelationFilter
    0
else
    if nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 0            // previous bar buyCountdown is 0
        if initiateBuyCountdown
            1
        else
            0
    else
        if nz(buyCountdown[1]) < 13        // previous bar 0 < buyCountdown < 13
            if newBuySetupDuringCountdown and (buyCancelationQualifier1 or buyCancelationQualifier2)
                1
            else
                if close <= low[2]
                    nz(buyCountdown[1]) + 1
                else
                    nz(buyCountdown[1])
        else                               // previous bar buyCountdown is 13
            if newBuySetupDuringCountdown and (buyCancelationQualifier1 or buyCancelationQualifier2)
                1
            else
                if buyCountdownCompleted
                    0
                else
                    nz(buyCountdown[1])    // completion is deferred until condition is satisfied

// Number Plots 
plotchar(buyCountdown!=buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==1 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='1',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==2 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='2',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp) 
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==3 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='3',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==4 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='4',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==5 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='5',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==6 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='6',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==7 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='7',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==8 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='8',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==9 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='9',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==10 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='10',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==11 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='11',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==12 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='12',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotshape(buyCountdown==13 and close <= low[2] and low > valuewhen(nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 7 and showBuyCountdown, close, 0), style=shape.cross, color=color.red, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(low <= valuewhen(nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0) and buyCountdown==13 and showBuyCountdown,text='13',textcolor=color.red,style=shape.arrowup,size=size.small,color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)

// COUNTDOWN - SELL //
 
// Cancelation Filter
brokeSupport = barssince(high < TDSTSupport) < sinceSellNine // full candle traded below current tdst support
sellCancelationFilter = lastSetupIsBuy or brokeSupport

// Cancelation Qualifier 1
lastSellHighestVal        = sellSetup == 9 ? highest(high, 9) : (sellSetup > 9 ? max(nz(lastSellHighestVal[1]), high) : nz(lastSellHighestVal[1]))
lastSellSetupRange        = lastSellHighestVal - TDSTSupport
secondLastSellRange       = sellSetup == 9 ? nz(lastSellSetupRange[1]) : nz(secondLastSellRange[1])
sellCancelationQualifier1 = (secondLastSellRange <= lastSellSetupRange) and (lastSellSetupRange < 1.618 * secondLastSellRange)

// Cancelation Qualifier 2
lastSellHighestClose      = sellSetup == 9 ? highest(close, 9) : (sellSetup > 9 ? max(nz(lastSellHighestClose[1]), close) : nz(lastSellHighestClose[1]))
lastSellLowestClose       = sellSetup == 9 ? lowest(close, 9) : (sellSetup > 9 ? min(nz(lastSellLowestClose[1]), close) : nz(lastSellLowestClose[1]))
secondLastSellHighestVal  = sellSetup == 9 ? nz(lastSellHighestVal[1]) : nz(secondLastSellHighestVal[1])
secondLastSellLowestVal   = sellSetup == 9 ? TDSTSupport[1] : nz(secondLastSellLowestVal[1])

aboveSecondLastSellRange  = lastSellHighestClose > secondLastSellHighestVal
belowSecondLastSellRange  = lastSellLowestClose < secondLastSellLowestVal
sinceSecondLastSell       = sellSetup == 9 ? nz(sinceSellNine[1])+1 : nz(sinceSecondLastSell[1])+1
buySetupBetweenTwoSells   = sinceSecondLastSell > sinceBuyNine and sinceBuyNine > sinceSellNine
sellCancelationQualifier2 = aboveSecondLastSellRange or belowSecondLastSellRange or buySetupBetweenTwoSells

// Miscellaneous
initiateSellCountdown       = (close >= high[2]) and (sellSetup == 9 or barssince(close[1] >= high[3])+1 > sinceSellNine)
sellCountdownCompleted      = high[1] >= valuewhen(nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0)
newSellSetupDuringCountdown = barssince(sellSetup == 9) < barssince(sellCountdown[1] == 1)

// Countdown Logic
sellCountdown = if sellCancelationFilter
    0
else
    if nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 0            // previous bar sellCountdown is 0
        if initiateSellCountdown
            1
        else
            0
    else
        if nz(sellCountdown[1]) < 13        // previous bar 0 < sellCountdown < 13
            if newSellSetupDuringCountdown and (sellCancelationQualifier1 or sellCancelationQualifier2)
                1
            else
                if close >= high[2]
                    nz(sellCountdown[1]) + 1
                else
                    nz(sellCountdown[1])
        else                                // previous bar sellCountdown is 13
            if newSellSetupDuringCountdown and (sellCancelationQualifier1 or sellCancelationQualifier1)
                1
            else
                if sellCountdownCompleted
                    0
                else
                    nz(sellCountdown[1])    // completion is deferred until condition is satisfied

// Number Plots
plotchar(sellCountdown!=sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==1 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='1',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==2 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='2',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==3 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='3',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==4 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='4',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==5 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='5',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==6 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='6',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==7 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='7',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==8 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='8',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==9 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='9',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==10 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='10',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==11 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='11',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==12 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='12',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotshape(sellCountdown==13 and close >= high[2] and high < valuewhen(nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 7 and showSellCountdown, close, 0), style=shape.cross, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(high >= valuewhen(nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0) and sellCountdown==13 and showSellCountdown,text='13',textcolor=color.green,style=shape.arrowdown,size=size.small,color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)

// RISK LINES //
 
buyCountdownLow = buyCountdown == 1 and nz(buyCountdown[1]) != 1 ? low : min(nz(buyCountdownLow[1]), low)
buyRiskLine = buyCountdown == 13 and low <= valuewhen(nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0) ? 2*buyCountdownLow - valuewhen(change(buyCountdownLow)!=0, high, 0) : nz(buyRiskLine[1])
buyRiskLineIntact = high >= buyRiskLine and (barssince(high < buyRiskLine) > barssince(buyCountdown == 13 and low <= valuewhen(nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0)))
plot(buyRiskLineIntact and showRiskLines ? buyRiskLine : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.purple)

sellCountdownHigh = sellCountdown == 1 and nz(sellCountdown[1]) != 1 ? high : max(nz(sellCountdownHigh[1]), high)
sellRiskLine = sellCountdown == 13 and high >= valuewhen(nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0) ? 2*sellCountdownHigh - valuewhen(change(sellCountdownHigh)!=0, low, 0) : nz(sellRiskLine[1])
sellRiskLineIntact = low <= sellRiskLine and (barssince(low > sellRiskLine) > barssince(sellCountdown == 13 and high >= valuewhen(nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0)))
plot(sellRiskLineIntact and showRiskLines ? sellRiskLine : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.purple)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you were trying to reference past instances of a series while that series didn't exist yet.

An example with `buyCountdownLow`
It references `buyCountdownLow[1]`, but at that moment this variable doesn't exists yet.

```
buyCountdownLow = buyCountdown == 1 and nz(buyCountdown[1]) != 1 ? low : min(nz(buyCountdownLow[1]), low)
```

This can be fixed by first defining `buyCountdownLow` and then using `:=` instead of `=` to assigning a value.

```
var float buyCountdownLow = na
buyCountdownLow := buyCountdown == 1 and nz(buyCountdown[1]) != 1 ? low : min(nz(buyCountdownLow[1]), low)
```

This will work:

```
// ==============================================
// TD Sequential - Setup and Countdown
// Igor Molnar, 2018.
// ==============================================
// Tom DeMark's Sequential indicator with both Setup and Countdown components implemented 
// according to the rules outlined in: DeMark Indicators by Jason Perl (Bloomberg Market Essentials)
// 
// Feel free to PM me your comments, suggestions and bug reports at https://www.tradingview.com/u/Yngvar/

//@version=4
study("TD Sequential (Setup and Countdown)", overlay = true)

// OPTIONAL PARAMETERS //

transp            = input(0, title="Number Transparency")
priceFlipRequired = input(true, title="Setup - Require price flip for initiation")
showBuySetup      = input(true, title="Setup - Show Buy Setup")
showSellSetup     = input(true, title="Setup - Show Sell Setup")
showOnlySetupNine = input(false,title="Setup - Show Only Completed Nines")
showResistance    = input(true, title="Setup Trend - Show Resistance Lines")
showSupport       = input(true, title="Setup Trend - Show Support Lines")
showBuyCountdown  = input(true, title="Countdown - Show Buy Countdown")
showSellCountdown = input(true, title="Countdown - Show Sell Countdown")
showRiskLines     = input(false, title="Risk Lines - Show (Beta)")

// PRICE FLIP AND SETUP //
var int buySetup = na
buySetup := if close < close[4]
    if priceFlipRequired
        if close[1] > close[5] or 0 < nz(buySetup[1])
            nz(buySetup[1]) + 1
        else
            0
    else
        if nz(buySetup[1]) == 9
            1
        else
            nz(buySetup[1]) + 1
else
    0

var int sellSetup = na 
sellSetup := if close > close[4]
    if priceFlipRequired
        if close[1] < close[5] or 0 < nz(sellSetup[1])
            nz(sellSetup[1]) + 1
        else
            0
    else
        if nz(sellSetup[1]) == 9
            1
        else
            nz(sellSetup[1]) + 1
else
    0

// PERFECTED SETUP CONDITIONS //

sellPerfection = sellSetup==9 and ((high > high[2] and high > high[3]) or (high[1] > high[2] and high[1] > high[3]))
buyPerfection  = buySetup==9 and ((low < low[2] and low < low[3]) or (low[1] < low[2] and low[1] < low[3]))

// NUMBER PLOTS //

plotchar(sellSetup==1 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='1',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==2 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='2',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==3 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='3',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==4 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='4',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==5 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='5',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==6 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='6',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==7 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='7',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellSetup==8 and showSellSetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='8',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotshape(sellSetup==9 and showSellSetup and not sellPerfection,style=shape.arrowdown,size=size.small,color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,text="9",textcolor=color.green,transp=transp)
plotshape(sellPerfection and showSellSetup,style=shape.arrowdown,size=size.small,color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,text="9P",textcolor=color.green,transp=transp)
 
plotchar(buySetup==1 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='1',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==2 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='2',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==3 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='3',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==4 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='4',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==5 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='5',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==6 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='6',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buySetup==7 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='7',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp) 
plotchar(buySetup==8 and showBuySetup and not showOnlySetupNine,char='8',color=color.red,location=location.abovebar,transp=transp)
plotshape(buyPerfection and showBuySetup,style=shape.arrowup,size=size.small,color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,text="9P",textcolor=color.red,transp=transp)
plotshape(buySetup==9 and not buyPerfection and showBuySetup,style=shape.arrowup,size=size.small,color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,text="9",textcolor=color.red,transp=transp)

// ALERTS // 

alertcondition(barssince(sellSetup == 9) == 1, title='Sell Setup Completed', message='TD Sell Setup Completed')
alertcondition(barssince(buySetup == 9) == 1, title='Buy Setup Completed', message='TD Buy Setup Completed')

// SETUP TREND LINES //
var float TDSTSupport = na
ll9 = lowest(low,9)
TDSTSupport := sellSetup == 9 ? ll9 : nz(TDSTSupport[1])
TDSTSupportIntact = close >= TDSTSupport and (barssince(close < TDSTSupport) > barssince(sellSetup == 9))
plot(TDSTSupportIntact and showSupport ? TDSTSupport : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.green)

var float TDSTResistance = na
hh9 = highest(high,9)
TDSTResistance := buySetup == 9 ? hh9 : nz(TDSTResistance[1])
TDSTResistanceIntact = close <= TDSTResistance and (barssince(close > TDSTResistance) > barssince(buySetup == 9))
plot(TDSTResistanceIntact and showResistance ? TDSTResistance : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.red)
 
// COUNTDOWN - BUY //

// Cancelation Filter 
sinceBuyNine      = barssince(buySetup == 9)
sinceSellNine     = barssince(sellSetup == 9)
lastSetupIsBuy    = sinceBuyNine < sinceSellNine // last completed setup is a buy setup
lastSetupIsSell   = not lastSetupIsBuy
brokeResistance   = barssince(low > TDSTResistance) < sinceBuyNine // did full candle trade above tdst resistance generated by last buy setup
buyCancelationFilter = lastSetupIsSell or brokeResistance

// Cancelation Qualifier 1 - Last buy setup larger than the one before but less then 1.618 times it's size
var float lastBuyLowestVal = na
var float secondLastBuyRange = na
lastBuyLowestVal         := buySetup == 9 ? ll9 : (buySetup > 9 ? min(nz(lastBuyLowestVal[1]), low) : nz(lastBuyLowestVal[1]))
lastBuySetupRange        = TDSTResistance - lastBuyLowestVal
secondLastBuyRange       := buySetup == 9 ? nz(lastBuySetupRange[1]) : nz(secondLastBuyRange[1])
buyCancelationQualifier1 = (secondLastBuyRange <= lastBuySetupRange) and (lastBuySetupRange < 1.618 * secondLastBuyRange)

// Cancelation Qualifier 2 - Last buy setup not within the last one
var float lastBuyHighestClose = na
var float lastBuyLowestClose = na
var float secondLastBuyHighestVal = na
var float secondLastBuyLowestVal = na
hc9 = highest(close, 9)
lc9 = lowest(close, 9)
lastBuyHighestClose      := buySetup == 9 ? hc9 : (buySetup > 9 ? max(nz(lastBuyHighestClose[1]), close) : nz(lastBuyHighestClose[1]))
lastBuyLowestClose       := buySetup == 9 ? lc9 : (buySetup > 9 ? min(nz(lastBuyLowestClose[1]), close) : nz(lastBuyLowestClose[1]))
secondLastBuyHighestVal  := buySetup == 9 ? TDSTResistance[1] : nz(secondLastBuyHighestVal[1])
secondLastBuyLowestVal   := buySetup == 9 ? nz(lastBuyLowestVal[1]) : nz(secondLastBuyLowestVal[1])

aboveSecondLastBuyRange  = lastBuyHighestClose > secondLastBuyHighestVal
belowSecondLastBuyRange  = lastBuyLowestClose < secondLastBuyLowestVal

var float sinceSecondLastBuy = na
sinceSecondLastBuy       := buySetup == 9 ? nz(sinceBuyNine[1])+1 : nz(sinceSecondLastBuy[1])+1
sellSetupBetweenTwoBuys  = sinceSecondLastBuy > sinceSellNine and sinceSellNine > sinceBuyNine
buyCancelationQualifier2 = aboveSecondLastBuyRange or belowSecondLastBuyRange or sellSetupBetweenTwoBuys

// Recycle Qualifier
recycleQualifier = buySetup == 18 // To do, a bit unclear

// Miscellaneous
var int buyCountdown = na
initiateBuyCountdown  = (close <= low[2]) and (buySetup == 9 or barssince(close[1] <= low[3])+1 > sinceBuyNine)
buyCountdownCompleted = low[1] <= valuewhen(nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0)
newBuySetupDuringCountdown = barssince(buySetup == 9) < barssince(buyCountdown[1] == 1)
        
// Countdown Logic
buyCountdown := if buyCancelationFilter
    0
else
    if nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 0            // previous bar buyCountdown is 0
        if initiateBuyCountdown
            1
        else
            0
    else
        if nz(buyCountdown[1]) < 13        // previous bar 0 < buyCountdown < 13
            if newBuySetupDuringCountdown and (buyCancelationQualifier1 or buyCancelationQualifier2)
                1
            else
                if close <= low[2]
                    nz(buyCountdown[1]) + 1
                else
                    nz(buyCountdown[1])
        else                               // previous bar buyCountdown is 13
            if newBuySetupDuringCountdown and (buyCancelationQualifier1 or buyCancelationQualifier2)
                1
            else
                if buyCountdownCompleted
                    0
                else
                    nz(buyCountdown[1])    // completion is deferred until condition is satisfied

// Number Plots 
plotchar(buyCountdown!=buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==1 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='1',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==2 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='2',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp) 
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==3 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='3',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==4 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='4',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==5 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='5',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==6 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='6',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==7 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='7',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==8 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='8',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==9 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='9',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==10 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='10',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==11 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='11',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(buyCountdown>buyCountdown[1] and buyCountdown==12 and showBuyCountdown,char='',text='12',color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotshape(buyCountdown==13 and close <= low[2] and low > valuewhen(nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 7 and showBuyCountdown, close, 0), style=shape.cross, color=color.red, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(low <= valuewhen(nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0) and buyCountdown==13 and showBuyCountdown,text='13',textcolor=color.red,style=shape.arrowup,size=size.small,color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)

// COUNTDOWN - SELL //
 
// Cancelation Filter
brokeSupport = barssince(high < TDSTSupport) < sinceSellNine // full candle traded below current tdst support
sellCancelationFilter = lastSetupIsBuy or brokeSupport

// Cancelation Qualifier 1
var float lastSellHighestVal = na
var float secondLastSellRange = na
lastSellHighestVal        := sellSetup == 9 ? hh9 : (sellSetup > 9 ? max(nz(lastSellHighestVal[1]), high) : nz(lastSellHighestVal[1]))
lastSellSetupRange        = lastSellHighestVal - TDSTSupport
secondLastSellRange       := sellSetup == 9 ? nz(lastSellSetupRange[1]) : nz(secondLastSellRange[1])
sellCancelationQualifier1 = (secondLastSellRange <= lastSellSetupRange) and (lastSellSetupRange < 1.618 * secondLastSellRange)

// Cancelation Qualifier 2
var float lastSellHighestClose = na
var float lastSellLowestClose = na
var float secondLastSellHighestVal = na
var float secondLastSellLowestVal = na
lastSellHighestClose      := sellSetup == 9 ? hc9 : (sellSetup > 9 ? max(nz(lastSellHighestClose[1]), close) : nz(lastSellHighestClose[1]))
lastSellLowestClose       := sellSetup == 9 ? lc9 : (sellSetup > 9 ? min(nz(lastSellLowestClose[1]), close) : nz(lastSellLowestClose[1]))
secondLastSellHighestVal  := sellSetup == 9 ? nz(lastSellHighestVal[1]) : nz(secondLastSellHighestVal[1])
secondLastSellLowestVal   := sellSetup == 9 ? TDSTSupport[1] : nz(secondLastSellLowestVal[1])

var float sinceSecondLastSell = na
aboveSecondLastSellRange  = lastSellHighestClose > secondLastSellHighestVal
belowSecondLastSellRange  = lastSellLowestClose < secondLastSellLowestVal
sinceSecondLastSell       := sellSetup == 9 ? nz(sinceSellNine[1])+1 : nz(sinceSecondLastSell[1])+1
buySetupBetweenTwoSells   = sinceSecondLastSell > sinceBuyNine and sinceBuyNine > sinceSellNine
sellCancelationQualifier2 = aboveSecondLastSellRange or belowSecondLastSellRange or buySetupBetweenTwoSells

// Miscellaneous
var int sellCountdown = na
var bool sellCountdownCompleted = na
initiateSellCountdown       = (close >= high[2]) and (sellSetup == 9 or barssince(close[1] >= high[3])+1 > sinceSellNine)
sellCountdownCompleted      := high[1] >= valuewhen(nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0)
newSellSetupDuringCountdown = barssince(sellSetup == 9) < barssince(sellCountdown[1] == 1)

// Countdown Logic
sellCountdown := if sellCancelationFilter
    0
else
    if nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 0            // previous bar sellCountdown is 0
        if initiateSellCountdown
            1
        else
            0
    else
        if nz(sellCountdown[1]) < 13        // previous bar 0 < sellCountdown < 13
            if newSellSetupDuringCountdown and (sellCancelationQualifier1 or sellCancelationQualifier2)
                1
            else
                if close >= high[2]
                    nz(sellCountdown[1]) + 1
                else
                    nz(sellCountdown[1])
        else                                // previous bar sellCountdown is 13
            if newSellSetupDuringCountdown and (sellCancelationQualifier1 or sellCancelationQualifier1)
                1
            else
                if sellCountdownCompleted
                    0
                else
                    nz(sellCountdown[1])    // completion is deferred until condition is satisfied

// Number Plots
plotchar(sellCountdown!=sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==1 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='1',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==2 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='2',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==3 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='3',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==4 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='4',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==5 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='5',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==6 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='6',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==7 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='7',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==8 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='8',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==9 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='9',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==10 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='10',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==11 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='11',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotchar(sellCountdown>sellCountdown[1] and sellCountdown==12 and showSellCountdown,char='',text='12',color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)
plotshape(sellCountdown==13 and close >= high[2] and high < valuewhen(nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 7 and showSellCountdown, close, 0), style=shape.cross, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(high >= valuewhen(nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0) and sellCountdown==13 and showSellCountdown,text='13',textcolor=color.green,style=shape.arrowdown,size=size.small,color=color.red,location=location.belowbar,transp=transp)

// RISK LINES //
var float buyCountdownLow = na
var float buyRiskLine = na
var bool buyRiskLineIntact = na
buyCountdownLow := buyCountdown == 1 and nz(buyCountdown[1]) != 1 ? low : min(nz(buyCountdownLow[1]), low)
vwb7 = valuewhen(nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0)
vwb0 = valuewhen(change(buyCountdownLow)!=0, high, 0)
buyRiskLine := buyCountdown == 13 and low <= vwb7 ? 2*buyCountdownLow - vwb0 : nz(buyRiskLine[1])
buyRiskLineIntact := high >= buyRiskLine and (barssince(high < buyRiskLine) > barssince(buyCountdown == 13 and low <= valuewhen(nz(buyCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0)))
plot(buyRiskLineIntact and showRiskLines ? buyRiskLine : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.purple)

var float sellCountdownHigh = na
var float sellRiskLine = na
var bool sellRiskLineIntact = na
sellCountdownHigh := sellCountdown == 1 and nz(sellCountdown[1]) != 1 ? high : max(nz(sellCountdownHigh[1]), high)
vws7 = valuewhen(nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0)
vws0 = valuewhen(change(sellCountdownHigh)!=0, low, 0)
sellRiskLine := sellCountdown == 13 and high >= vws7 ? 2*sellCountdownHigh - vws0 : nz(sellRiskLine[1])
sellRiskLineIntact := low <= sellRiskLine and (barssince(low > sellRiskLine) > barssince(sellCountdown == 13 and high >= valuewhen(nz(sellCountdown[1]) == 7, close, 0)))
plot(sellRiskLineIntact and showRiskLines ? sellRiskLine : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.purple)
```